# Layers are not visible after using a custom orthographic projection in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, globe

I was planning to make a global orthographic map, that would show country borders and oceans. Therefore,[i followed this method](http://www.statsmapsnpix.com/2019/09/globe-projections-and-insets-in-qgis.html) which plots a map similar to my requirements. However, i modified the codes so that the map is centered on Asia:

```
+proj=ortho +lat_0=10 +lon_0=90 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs
```

Although the land areas were projected just fine, i was having problem with the ocean's layer, as you can see in these pictures: [image][image]

I decided to change the projection of the ocean layer to the custom projection, but that makes the ocean layer entirely invisible:
[image]

There has been a similar question regarding this problem at [Using azimuthal orthographic projection in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127328), where it was suggested to use uncheck the simplify geometry options in the layer rendering, but that didn't work for me.

How do I properly project the ocean layer in the globe, like in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Please clafiry what you mean by "I decided to change" - did you transform/save the layer to the custom CRS, or did you just set the CRS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I set the CRS of the ocean layer to the custom projection.

Comment: Yeah, and this is why the layer disappeared. Setting the CRS is the wrong option in most cases.

Comment: Well in that case, what do you suggest i should be doing ?

Comment: The other option I outlined.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when a layer passes the visible "half" of the globe the general recommendation is cutting the layer at the "edge" longitudes  of your custom projection. You can follow the instructions shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78346/ortho-projection-produces-artifacts/78441) and [here](https://polemic.nz/2014/11/21/nz-azimuth-orthographic/)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I went through the two solution that you mentioned. I created a pyhton script, saved it as "cliportho.py" in the qgis pyhton folder "....apps\Python37\lib\cliportho.py". I imported cliportho and called it in the python console using ```cliportho.doClip(iface, lat=10, lon=90, filename='ne_10m_ocean.shp')``` as those are my desired coordinates. but it returns mw with the following error: ```TypeError: QgsCoordinateTransform(): arguments did not match any overloaded call: 
  overload 5: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem' ``` .

Comment: Yeah i guess you need to update the script with the new pyqgis api because that script is pre-qgis3.